# Feedback on shared view with form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I have my main shared view (_Layout) with this:

```
<div class="slide-out-div">
    <a class="handle" href="http://link-for-non-js-users">Content</a>
    @{Html.RenderAction("Feedback", "Home");}
</div>
```

It is a slide panel (works, nothing to worry about) that contains a form. (Feedback.cshtml)
That controller/action gets the correct view but when I do the submit, the whole view is updated, and I just want that "RenderAction" to be updated with another view saying "Thank you"

My form (Feedback.cshtml) looks like this:

```
@model project.FeedbackViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Feedback";
}

<h2>Feedback</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Feedback", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p>User:</p>
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</p>
    <p>Last Name:</p>
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.UserEmail, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</p>

    <p>Message:</p>
    <p>@Html.TextAreaFor(m=>m.Description, new { @cols = 80, @rows = 10 })</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

and the Action called:

public ActionResult Feedback()
        {
            //blah blah blah

```
        return PartialView(fbVM);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Feedback(FeedbackViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //put data in DB
            return View("~/Views/Home/FeedbackThanks.cshtml");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Should I return a PartialView? change the RenderAction? What am I doing wrong?

The get method works.
The return View solution gives this error:

> Exception Details: System.InsufficientExecutionStackException:
>   Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can
>   happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on
>   the stack using too much stack space.

And if I use PartialView instead, the whole page will render the new view instead of just the feedback div.